# How to resolve the issue as “A network related instance specific error”

Tags: windows-firewall, azure-sql-database, management-studio-express

I trying to connect azure SQL database from SQL Server Management studio and also trying connect from SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio 2015, at that time I got the Exception like “A network related instance specific error”.

If you want more details about my exception, see the below figure.

[image]
I tried with added my IP address in azure database firewall settings but I didn’t connect to my azure SQL database.

Can you please tell me how can I resolve the above issue?

-Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

if you are still facing this issue, can you please check your TCP/IP connection settings are okay?

I am the Availability PM for Azure SQL DB. If that's also okay and if the problem is persisting, could you please email me the server name and database name to ravenk at microsoft dot com. I'll investigate this and get back to you.

Thanks.
Rahul.